# Problem with StringReplace and RegularExpressions

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I have list of strings that I need to replace the last two characters. I am using RegularExpression to distinguish between "A1" and "A15". The problem that I am having is that when I try to replace the string found by the RegularExpression it returns the whole right hand side.

```
var = {"exampleA1","exampleA15"}

StringReplace[var, RegularExpression["A\\w+"] -> {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}]
```

> {"example" ~~ {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}, 
>    "example" ~~ {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}, 
>    "example" ~~ {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}, 
>    "example" ~~ {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}}

Answer (score 6):

If you want `"A"` followed by digits then you should be using `\d+` instead of `\w+`.  However that is not the real issue.

With

```
var = {"exampleA1", "exampleA15"};
rep = {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"};
```

Then

```
StringReplace[var, a : ("A" ~~ DigitCharacter ..) ~~ EndOfString :> (a /. rep)]
```

or

```
StringReplace[var, a : RegularExpression["A\\d+$"] :> (a /. rep)]
```

gives

> ```
> {"examplefoo", "examplecat"}
> ```

`EndOfString` (`$` in Regex) is not strictly needed in this case but it will make a difference if the pattern could occur elsewhere in the string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\[RuleDelayed]` symbol,  `:>` to apply a function to your expression. In this case, you want to apply additional rules to the pattern you find, I use `ReplaceAll` symbol, `/.` in the below answer.

```
StringReplace[var, a : RegularExpression["A\\w+"] :> (a /. {"A1" -> "foo", 
   "A15" -> "cat"})]
```

> {"exampleA1", "exampleA15"}

In your example, your entire regex gets replaced by `{"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"}` which isn't a string so you see the `StringExpression` operators in your result `~~`

**EDIT**

Added some missing syntax `()` to the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help, But it still isn't replacing A1 and A15 with "foo" and  "cat", respectively.

Comment: Add parentheses around the right-hand side: `StringReplace[var, 
 a : RegularExpression[
    "A\\w+"] :> (a /. {"A1" -> "foo", "A15" -> "cat"})]`

Comment: @Paul sorry about that @ WReach noticed I was missing some parentheses

Comment: No problem and thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Slightly cheating:

```
StringReplace[#, {"A15" -> "cat", "A1" -> "foo"}] & /@ var
```

> {"examplefoo", "examplecat"}

i.e. the `"Anumber"` must be in descending order, like `{"A16", "A8", "A5"}`, but not `{"A16", "A5", "A8"}`.

Comment: It is sufficient to write `StringReplace[var, {"A15" -> "cat", "A1" -> "foo"}]` (the use of `/@` is unnecessary).